# How to convert every list element in decimal from binary (Optimized way)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list , `list1 = [110,101,110]` how can I convert every list element in Decimal form so that list1 will be `[6,5,6]`

It is given that those list elements contains only 0's and 1's

since the list data may be large , I am looking for an **optimized solution**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `list1 = [110 , 101,110]` doesn't contain "binary". Those are `int` objects.

Comment: `list(map(lambda bits: int(f'0b{bits}',2), [110,101,110]))`. Convert the numbers you already have to a string and prepend "0b" to get it to binary format. Then you can use `int(bin_str, 2)` to convert it to an integer.

Comment: @Chrispresso "and prepend "0b" " why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
list1 = [110,101,110]
def binaryToDecimal(n):
    return int(n,2)
x = [binaryToDecimal(str(bins)) for bins in list1]
```

Shortened Version

```
x = [int(str(bins),2) for bins in list1]
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote it but why are you doing all that? Why are you converting the number from integer to string and then back to integer? Also, you are creating a new list from the results, why not change the values in that same list?

Comment: I'll answer your first one. You try and give the function integers. Where I say (str(bins)), get rid of he str and see what you get

Answer (score -2):

You mean like that?

```
list = []
for binary in list1:
     decimal = int(binary, 2)
     list.append(decimal)
```

But since your list elements are integers and not binaries this will not work.